# KeyError: None of Float64Index are in the [columns], not sure how to proceed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key, keyerror

I'm trying to return all rows from my Dataframe where two conditions are met.

The first condition works just fine. The second condition (where I try to use nlargest(10) to return the rows based on top 10 scores) gives me the following error:

```
 File "/Users/[extracted]/Desktop/imdbnew.py", line 21, in <module>
    comedy_high = IMDB[IMDB['Score'].nlargest(10)]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2806, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1552, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1640, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([9.6, 9.4, 9.4, 9.4, 9.4, 9.3, 9.2, 9.1, 9.1, 9.0], dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"
```

The code that produces this error is as follows:

```
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy

# Import IMDB data
data = pandas.read_csv('movies.csv')
col = data[['Title', 'Year', 'Score', 'Genre', 'Director',
                'Runtime', 'Revenue']]

IMDB = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Title', 'Year', 'Score', 'Genre',
                                         'Director', 'Runtime', 'Revenue'])


comedy_high = IMDB[IMDB['Score'].nlargest(10)]
#comedy_df = IMDB[(IMDB['Genre'].str.contains("Comedy"))]

print(comedy_high)
```

If, however, I try to just print out the top 10 scores, and not return the rows corresponding to it from the Dataframe, I do get a result:

```
comedy_high = IMDB['Score'].nlargest(10)
```

Where the result is:

```
9603    9.6
1645    9.4
3914    9.4
5482    9.4
5979    9.4
0       9.3
9       9.2
5428    9.1
6891    9.1
1       9.0
Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

This has been truly frustrating me, can someone please help out? I'm a novice programmer; I've been reading other similar questions, and testing out answers provided, but am unable to reach a solution. I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: This may be because the two statements return different things. `.str.contains()` returns a pandas Series object (having the same number of rows as the original dataframe) with boolean values in it -- this can be used to filter. `.nlargest()` returns a pandas Series object with a variable number of rows and values of any dtype in it (float in your example) -- this cannot be used to filter.

Comment: Thank you Ankur for pointing that out! I was able to use this information to go a different approach and was able to find a solution to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to solve what I was looking for with the following code:

```
comedy_df = IMDB[(IMDB['Genre'].str.contains("Comedy"))]
comedy = pandas.DataFrame(comedy_df)
comedy_high = comedy.sort_values('Score', ascending=False).head(10)
print(comedy_high)
```

As Ankur mentioned in his comment, I wasn't able to use .nlargest() to filter the Dataframe. I instead created a filtered version of my original Dataframe based on the genre I was looking into, sorted the Scores in a descending order, and used .head() to get the top n values.